# A good place to start would be (with)

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about some sentence in this [Economist article](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21722642-lot-known-about-how-reform-prisoners-far-too-little-done-americas-prisons-are):

> Reserve prison for the worst offenders. Divert the less scary ones to drug treatment, community service and other penalties that do not mean severing ties with work, family and normality. ***A good place to start would be with most of the 2.6m prisoners in the world***...who are still awaiting trial.

How would the bold part be different if the "*with*" after "*would be*" is dropped:

> A good place to start would be most of the 2.6m prisoners in the world...who are still awaiting trial.

Comment: The original is slightly less awkward than the version without "with".  *We could begin with the 2.6m prisoners ... awaiting trial*.   **place** is the problem.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How about moving "*with*" to just after "*to start*":  "A good place to start ***with***" would be most of the 2.6m prisoners in the world...who are still awaiting trial. "?

Comment: Is your goal to make it marginally acceptable or to state the idea clearly and succinctly?  [a good place... is most] or [a good place ... would be most]  don't work for me.

Comment: A good **way** to begin would be **to divert** most of the 2.6m prisoners awaiting trial.

Comment: Prisoners aren't a place. You start at the place they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Start by simplifying the sentence a bit (to remove clutter); for instance:

> One place to start is with prisoners awaiting trial.

This simplification helps to understand that the subject of the sentence is **place** and then the infinitive *to start* acts as an adjective modifying **place** and then a copula, or linking verb, and a phrase modifying **place**.

From Collins English Dictionary

> copula /ˈkɒpjʊlə/  noun (pl) -las, -lae (-ˌliː) 
>   1. a verb, such as be, seem, or taste, that is used merely to identify or link the subject with the complement of a sentence. Copulas may
>   serve to link nouns (or pronouns), as in he became king, nouns (or
>   pronouns) and adjectival complements, as in sugar tastes sweet, or
>   nouns (or pronouns) and adverbial complements, as in John is in jail
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/copula?s=t

Once we've started to get a better grasp of the elements of this sentence we now can begin to realize there is an understood *"to start"* after the verb *is*, so the actual simplified sentence becomes:

> One place to start is [to start] with prisoners awaiting trial.

And in this case the word *place* means (from Collins English Dictionary):

> 3. a position or rank in a sequence or order
>      http://www.dictionary.com/browse/place?s=t

We know that there is these unstated, understood words in the sentence because we know that the complement after the linking verb has to modify the noun, and so we should be able to remove the adverb *to start* prior to the verb and the sentence should sound correct.  However,

> One place is with prisoners awaiting trial.

is incorrect. Similarly,

> One place is prisoners awaiting trial.

(removing the word *with* as was asked in the question) also is incorrect.  So we know we need

> One place is [to start] with prisoners awaiting trial.

So, after adding the understood words *to start* after the verb, it should become clear that we cannot remove the word *with*, because

> One place is [to start] prisoners awaiting trial.

is incorrect.

Returning to the full sentence:

> A good place to start would be [to start] with most of the 2.6m prisoners in the
>   world...who are still awaiting trial.

The examples from the simplified sentences above will hold true and the word *with* is necessary for the same reasons as in the simplified sentences.